# Table border difference IE9 vs IE8

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-9, border

IE9 displays table, th and td borders differently from IE8. What is the reason for this and what can be done about it?
As can be seen from below screen prints, the borders seem to have a shaded effect in IE9 which  causes them to be not as crisp any more as they were in IE8. This seems to apply to solid (table, th) as well as dotted (td) borders.

html used

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>table border test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
table {
    border: solid black 1pt;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 153);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1pt;
    padding: 0cm 5pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td {
    border-style: dotted dotted none none;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1pt;
    padding: 0cm 5pt;
    color: black;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 4.5pt;
    margin-top: 0pt;
}

    </style>
      </head>
   <body>
      <br>

      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="small">col A</th>
               <th class="small">col B</th>
               <th class="large">col C</th>
               <th class="medium">col D</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td align="center">A1</td>
               <td align="center">B1</td>
               <td>C1</td>
               <td>D1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align="center">A2</td>
               <td align="center">B2</td>
               <td>C2</td>
               <td>D2</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

IE8 result

[image: IE8 result]

IE9 result

[image: IE9 result]

Comment: I'd guess it is improved subpixel rendering caused by you not using a whole number of pixels for the size of the border. Don't use `pt` units for screen media.

Comment: Tried it and succeeded - promote your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pt` unit is a physical unit (1/72 of an inch). Newer versions of IE probably use subpixel rendering when given something to render that doesn't have a whole number of pixels.

Physical units are poorly served on screen anyway (as browsers often make poor assumptions about the DPI of the screen), so should be reserved for print media.

Use `px` instead.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not round down your 1pt border to 1px. It's not a bug, it's a feature!

To solve this you can use px instead of pt, and make sure to use whole numbers.